# ImageButton event does not fire if ImageButton does not have Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it normal behavior for an ImageButton event to not fire if it can't find the image for it.  For example, assume I have the following piece of code:

```
imageLink = new ImageButton();
imageLink.ImageUrl = "~/images/arrow.png";
```

If the page finds arrow.png, the image click works, but if it doesn't find it, it does not work.

These images are created dynamically and a CommandName, CommandArgument and Click Handler are assigned.

```
void imageLink_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
    Detail oDetail = new Detail();

    switch(button.CommandName)
    {
        case "Band":
             oDetail.Band  = button.CommandArgument;
                break;
            case "State":
                oDetail.State = button.CommandArgument;
                break;
        }                    

        Session["Page2"] = oDetail;

        Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no answers, but I've seen this exact same thing happpening in Firefox on .NET sites.  Always curious to know if there is an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, it happens
Image button events are not firing sometime without image
Anybody know the exact reason behind this issue, 
please post here

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not normal.  I just tested and even if you never set `ImageUrl` the button will still post back.  Are you certain that the issue is not related to event handling?

Comment: This is my event handler:
imageLink.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageLink_Click);

Comment: Can you post more code?  I am specifically interested in knowing where you attach the event handler (as in what part of the ASP.NET life-cycle) and what imageLink_Click method looks like.

Comment: It creates the event in Page_Load.  I will post code for the imageLink_Click

Answer (score 0):

yes, that's right. If the ImageButton doesn't have an ImageUrl declared, it won't fire the onclick event. It will cause a Postback, but the event isn't fired.

This code won't fire the event

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="testImgBtn" ImageUrl="" runat="server" onclick="testImgBtn_Click" />
```

while this does:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="testImgBtn" ImageUrl="http://www.google.it/intl/en_en/images/logo.gif" runat="server" onclick="testImgBtn_Click" />
```